# Facebook and Android - user_groups permission

Tags: android, facebook

I just received the result of the review of my android app that should use the user_groups permission. They said that my submission is not approved because

```
The user_groups permission is only approved for apps that let people use Facebook on platforms where Facebook is not already available.
If you're building an app on Android and iOS, for example, you won't be approved for this permission. Web, Desktop and TV apps will also not be granted this permission.
```

I understand the reason why my submission has been unapproved but searching on the Play Store, I can find a lot of reent app that actually have this permission granted (they show a list of user's group). So, there is a way to obtain this? Is there any other way to read user group's list?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Those Apps are using an older Facebook App created before end of April 2014. They can still use v1.0 of the Graph API, and they don´t need to go through the review process until end of April 2015. They will stop working after that date, because they will not get approved with user_groups.

So there is no way to obtain this permission, unfortunately. Unless you still got a Facebook App created before end of April 2014, but it will definitely stop working after April 2015 so there is no point in using user_groups.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! Anyway, this is kinda frustating ...this permission could give us a lot of possibility for generating very interesting apps... :/

Comment: well, i guess they are careful with that permission now because there is a lot of spam going in in facebook groups...and with user_groups and publish_actions, you were able to post.

Comment: Well, so they should not give those permission for the same app...but ok..this is it... :/